# Determining text clicked on with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a html element and I would like to know which individual character in the element was clicked on, is there any way of accomplishing this using javascript/jQuery short of separating each character into its own element.

Comment: I've got to think that separating into spans is really the only viable solution, at least currently.

Answer (score 0):

hmm... here are some ideas

1. Dumb and quick

   ```
   <p onclick="clicked('a')";>a</p>
   <p onclick="clicked('b')";>b</p>
   <p onclick="clicked('c')";>c</p>
   ```

style to fit.

1. Tedious and no idea if tweakable

html....

```
<p id="text" onclick="which(event)">abcde</p>
```

js...

```
function which(event) {
    var offsetX = $("#text").offset().left;
    var mX = event.x-offsetX;
    // use event.clientX for firefox and so on
    if (mX < 5) {
        alert("a");
    }   else if (mX < 20) {
        alert("b");
    }   else if (mX < 32) {
        alert("c");
    }   else if (mX < 43) {
        alert("d");
    }   else if (mX < 56) {
        alert("e");
    }
}
```

Although I have no idea how to keep the letter width of a p element as a constant...

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the duplicate question. I had tried searching several different times, but could only find answers for text positions in a text area. Unfortunately it does not seem feasible to include every text character on a page in its own span, so I guess I will look for other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slow code but couldn't figure out a better way to do it :

```
$('yourTarget').html(function(_,t){
    return t.replace(/(.)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
}).on('click', 'span', function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bT4XX/